# Can't load bot data because no implicit conversion of nil into String (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby

I'm currently going through "Beginning Ruby", Chapter 12, "Beginning Ruby-ChatterBox" where it builds a conversation bot. When running the basic_client.rb file, I get an error message:

```
: Can't load bot data because no implicit conversion of nil into String (RuntimeError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/bot.rb:13:in `initialize'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/basic_client.rb:4:in `new'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/basic_client.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Similar questions have been asked in the past. I consulted these examples but still can't solve this problem. Please I would appreciate if anyone could help with letting me know what I am doing wrong. Here is an extract of my code files. Please if extra information is needed, I would be glad to let you know.

bot.rb:

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'wordplay'

#A basic implementation of a chatterbox
class Bot
  attr_reader :name

  #Initialies the bot object, loads in the external YAML data
  # file and sets bot's name. Raises an exception if
  # the data loading process fails.
  def initialize(options)
    @name = options[:name] || "Unnamed Bot"
    begin
      @data = YAML.load(File.read(options[:data_file]))
    rescue => e
      raise "Can't load bot data because #{e}"
    end
  end
```

end

basic_client.rb:

```
require_relative 'bot'

bot = Bot.new(:name => ARGV[0], :data_file => ARGV[1])

puts bot.greeting

while input = $stdin.gets and input.chomp != 'end'
  puts '>> ' + bot.response_to(input)

end

puts bot.farewell
```

Comment: How are you running basic_client.rb from the command line? What arguments are you passing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question it's important to phrase a title that indicates the problem, not the book or website/blog you're reading. `"Can't load bot data because no implicit conversion of nil into String (RuntimeError)"` would be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
YAML.load(nil)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

so you should be careful: the result of `File.read(options[:data_file])` is probably nil.

```
YAML.load(nil.to_s)
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in your error message:

```
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/bot.rb:13:in `initialize'
```

Line 13 of bot.rb, in your initialize method.

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String (RuntimeError)
```

It can't turn nil into a string.

Your code specifies:

```
@name = options[:name] || "Unnamed Bot"
```

Which guards against options[:name] being nil

However

```
 @data = YAML.load(File.read(options[:data_file]))
```

Specifies that it tries to load a file with a path of `options[:data_file]`. Which is nil.

So when running your client ensure to pass your name AND the data file where the yaml should be loaded from. OR create a default file and pass that:

```
 @data = YAML.load(File.read(options[:data_file] || 'path/to/default.yml'))
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. one step further but trying to solve a no method error problem now. : undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
 from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/bot.rb:23:in `greeting'
 from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/basic_client.rb:7:in `<main>'

Comment: If it solved your question, please consider accepting the answer and upvote. If you have an additional question please post as new question.